# Django DB constraint - allow only one object with status field that is not "draft"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-constraints

I have a model `Application` with fields `bank`, `mortgage` and `status`. For same `bank` and `mortgage` I want to allow only one `application` with `status` different from DRAFT.

```
class Application(..):
    bank = ..
    mortgage = ..
    status = .. # draft, active, in_progress etc.
```

So there can be multiple applications like these:

```
# ok
Application(bank=1, mortgage=2, status='draft') 

# ok, tuple mortgage and bank already exists but but status is draft
Application(bank=1, mortgage=2, status='draft') 

# ok, tuple mortgage and bank already exists but status is active
Application(bank=1, mortgage=2, status='active') 

# ERROR - tuple mortgage and bank already exists and there is already one object with non-draft status
Application(bank=1, mortgage=2, status='in_progress') 

# ok - bank is different
Application(bank=3, mortgage=2, status='active')
```

In words, I can't create an application with same bank and same mortgage and status that is not `draft` if there is already an application with same bank and mortgage and status that is not `draft`.

Is it possible to do such constraint? Would `CheckConstraint` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#condition) with a condition

```
class Application(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['bank', 'mortgage'],
                condition=~models.Q(status='draft'),
                name='unique_non_draft'
            )
        ]
```

The above creates a unique constraint on combinations of `bank` and `mortgage` but only when the status is not "draft"